# How to use a while loop condition without initializing a boolean twice?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

What is the best way to simply this expression so that I don't have to set colFinished twice? (colFinished has to be reset to false in each run of the outer loop)

```
boolean colFinished = false;
    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c += 1) {
        colFinished = false;
        while (!colFinished) {
            for (int r = 1; r < SIZE; r++) {
            ...
```

Comment: "colFinished has to be reset to false in each run of the outer loop" - Why? There is no apparent reason for that.

Comment: If you want the boolean flag `colFinished` because you wish to `break` from the inner for-loop, you might want to consider using a label.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I haven't made that clear in the little snippet I gave you, but each run of the outer loop is a different column, so I reset my check on whether the column is finished.

Comment: Looking at your code, I feel like `do..while` may suit you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no use of `colFinished` outside the `for` loop, try :

```
for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c += 1) {
    boolean colFinished = false;
    ...............
```

Else I think there is no other way.

Comment: A good compiler would optimize your code, because you declare colFinished in the loop. Declare it outside and just set it false inside the loop.

Comment: @null : yes. but I think OP is not aware of this type of syntax. That's why  such a question is being asked.

Comment: @null If the variable has only meaning inside the loop, then I highly advise for declaring it inside the loop. This is all about intention. Let the compiler do its work. As a programmer you should write readable code that carries your intention!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your variable inside the first for-loop:

```
for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c += 1) {
    boolean colFinished = false;
    while (!colFinished) {
        for (int r = 1; r < SIZE; r++) {
        ...
```